# How to use index.cond in lattice?

Tags: r, lattice

I need to understand how to use `index.cond` in `lattice`. I am conditioning my graph on a factor called source of irrigation which has 6 levels i.e.

```
levels(irr_atlas2$irr_source)
# [1] "Govt. Canals"   "Other Sources"  "Other Wells"    "Private Canals" "Tanks"          "Tubewells"
```

Now I want to change the order of the panels such as the panel corresponding to Tubewells is drawn first followed by Other Wells,Tanks, Govt. Canals, Private Canals and Other sources. How can I do this using `index.cond`? I tried using `index.cond = list( c(6,3,5,1,4,2))` but it did not give me the desired result.

Comment: It gives govt canals in the top most left panel followed by private canals and other sources. then in the second panel it gives tubewells in the left-most panel followed by other-wells and tanks

Comment: So it follows the order you gave. With lattice, the starting point is the lower left corner. Just reverse your `index.cond`.

Comment: can you tell me using the c notation I am confused? Please elaborate

Comment: `index.cond = list(c(1,4,2,6,3,5))`

Comment: You could retain the index order you give above and set `as.table = TRUE`.

Comment: @Pascal  when I add layout=c(1,1) index.cond no longer seems to work? Why is that, am I doing something counter-intuitive?

Comment: You ask for 1 row x 1 column, i.e. 1 panel.

Comment: @Pascal, could you please elaborate the, how can I change if Tube-wells appear first etc in this case?

Comment: You want a plot with 3 x 2 panels, but with argument  `layout=c(1,1)`, you ask `lattice` to plot only one panel (1 row x 1 column).

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. As somebody suggested in the comments, lattice orders panels from the bottom up. To get what you want either use `as.table = TRUE` or reverse the ordering in `index.cond`.

Here's an example:

```
dd <- data.frame(
  x = runif(120),
  ind = gl(6, 1, labels = c("Govt. Canals", "Other Sources", "Other Wells",
                            "Private Canals", "Tanks", "Tubewells"))
)

library(lattice)

densityplot(~ x | ind, data = dd, as.table = TRUE,
            index.cond = list(c(6, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2)))
```

[image: Imgur]